# RDO Connection Time Out Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, rdo

When I run the query through VB6, I am getting error as "Time Out Expired"

For ADO Connection, I used `addConn.CommandTimeout = 1000`

For RDO Connection, How can i used CommandTimeout..?

Comment: You don't need to say "Need VB6 Code Help" every time, that is implied in the tags.

Comment: How long is it taking before you get the time out expired? There might be a command timeout default on your connection which is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in RDO is the [QueryTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263003%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

It can be set (in seconds) as below:

```
rdoConnection.QueryTimeout = 60
rdoPreparedStatement.QueryTimeout = 60
rdoQuery.QueryTimeout = 60
```